# Predefined ELF Code Sections

Tags: linker, elf, codewarrior

What are the predefined code sections that can be referenced in an ELF linker command file?  In addition to any others that may be available, I am specifically wondering about these:

- .text
- .rodata
- .sdata
- .sbss
- .bss
- .data

Finding documentation has proven most difficult.  If anyone can also tell me what the acronym ELF stands for in this context, that would be a plus.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about not finding documentation. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) has a large collection of links about the Executable and Linkable Format. One of the links there describes the ELF [sections](https://web.archive.org/web/20121126063759/http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/elf.html) you are interested in (plus lots of other stuff). Another link [here](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-PPC64/LSB-Core-PPC64/specialsections.html) describes additional ELF special sections (.sbss/.sdata).

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: @BulatM.Thanks.  Fortunately, the Internet Archive has a copy of that page, so I've referenced it now since the other link is gone.